# Forecast w/ AR(3) model using Y0 data error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

So I'm using an arima(3,0,0) model to forecast values in Matlab. I have a vector of initial values for it to use to forecast off of but I keep getting an error.
Here is my code:

```
model1=arima(3,0,0);
[EstMdl1,~,logL1]=estimate(model1,qtrdatachangelog2000(:,1));
Ymdl1pred=zeros(length(qtrdatachangelogafter2000),1);
for i=1:length(qtrdatachangelogafter2000)-2;
    [Ymdl1pred(i)]=forecast(EstMdl1,1,'Y0',qtrdatachangelogafter2000(i+2,1));
end;
```

The error I get:
Error using internal.econ.LagIndexableTimeSeries.checkPresampleData (line 653)
Number of rows in presample array 'Y0' must be at least 3.

Error in arima/forecast (line 498)
   Y0 = internal.econ.LagIndexableTimeSeries.checkPresampleData(zeros(maxPQ,numPaths),
   'Y0', Y0, OBJ.P);

I'm assuming this is because the AR(3) has 3 parameters and thus needs at least 3 rows of data before it can start which is why in my for loop I used i+2 but it continues to give the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `i+2` you are not adding 3 rows, you are using only 1 row. You need to specify the start and end index: `i:i+2`. You can use this code:

```
[Ymdl1pred(i)]=forecast(EstMdl1,1,'Y0',qtrdatachangelogafter2000(i:i+2,1));
```